# How to unite function index and function data to one new function?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, graph, highcharts, controller

I have a problem, in my application base on CodeIgniter.
One of my web page showing a graph or chart that is on the controller in the form of two functions: the function of index and data functions, "function index" contains only the call display, while the function data is contains data taken.

I've been trying to integrate these two functions but fails, the function fails to load JSON data contained in the data function, the following is the code in my controller:

```
public function index(){

$this->load->view(index);
}
public function data(){
$nis = 10012589; $tahun = 1;
$category = array();
        $category['name'] = 'Category';
        $category['data'] = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12');        
        $series1 = array();
        $series1['name'] = 'Masalah siswa';
        $series1['data'] = array(
            $dt[0]->h1,
            $dt[0]->h2,
            $dt[0]->h3,
            $dt[0]->h4,
            $dt[0]->h5,
            $dt[0]->h6,
            $dt[0]->h7,
            $dt[0]->h8,
            $dt[0]->h9,
            $dt[0]->h10,
            $dt[0]->h11,
            $dt[0]->h12
            ); 
        $result = array();
        array_push($result,$category);
        array_push($result,$series1);

    print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

}
```

and my **view** code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'column',
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    borderRadius: 20
                },
                xAxis: {                    
                    categories: [],
                    title: {
                        text: 'Topik Masalah'
                    }
            },

                series: []
            }
            /* */
            $.getJSON("data", function(json) {
                options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
                options.series[0] = json[1];                

                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });
            /* */
        });
        </script>
<div id="container" ></div>
```

I want to unite that code **in one function** and just one
But I don't know how because I'm a newbie

I hope you're understand what I asked

 thanks

Comment: Do You want to use Your `data()` result in `index()`? Anyway You must read about MVC, because Your `data()` seems to be in Model, not at Controller.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are printing your json and that is causing the issue because you are skipping the output buffer. You need to also set the headers in the output class. By default codeigniter sets HTML headers. But jquery expects JSON headers.

You also need to output your data using the output class not the print method, never use prints or echo in codeigniter outside of a view. Here the documentation you need.http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/output.html The two methods you need are `set_output(data)` and `set_content_type(content)`. Good luck.